# How do I create a file with touch in 12.10

Tags: 12.10, files

I need to create a file in Ubuntu to use a USB cradle to upload Cycling data. I found instructions using google but am unable to create a file using touch.

Any help would be appreciated. This is the direction I am trying to follow: Create a file `/etc/udev/rules/powertap.rules` containing the following line:

```
SYSFS{idVendor}=="0403", SYSFS{idProduct}=="6001", MODE="666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

Comment: sudo touch /etc/udev/rules/powertap.rules
[sudo] password for "username": 
touch: cannot touch `/etc/udev/rules/powertap.rules': No such file or directory

Comment: FWIW my USB port gives a permission error. I used "sudo usermod -G dialout user" to fix this problem but it also removed my username as root so I could sudo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If typing `cd /etc/udev/rules` results in

```
bash: cd: /etc/udev/rules: No such file or directory
```

Then you are missing that directory and you need to create it first using

```
sudo mkdir /etc/udev/rules
```

After that use one of the other posted suggestions such as:

```
sudo echo "SYSFS{idVendor}==\"0403\", SYSFS{idProduct}==\"6001\", MODE=\"666\", GROUP=\"plugdev\"" > /etc/udev/rules/powertap.rules
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I sort of figured this out but appreciate the imput

Answer (score 1):

Touch merely changes file timestamps. It does create a file but you can do it using gedit and be able to edit it. Touch doesn't edit file contents.

This may work :

`touch ~/powertap.rules; cat>>SYSFS{idVendor}=="0403", SYSFS{idProduct}=="6001", MODE="666", GROUP="plugdev"; sudo cp ~/powertap.rules /etc/udev/rules/powertap.rules`

Comment: touch ~/powertap.rules; cat>>SYSFS{idVendor}=="0403", SYSFS{idProduct}=="6001", MODE="666", GROUP="plugdev"; sudo cp ~/powertap.rules /etc/udev/rules/powertap.rules
cat: SYSFS{idProduct}==6001,: No such file or directory
cat: MODE=666,: No such file or directory
cat: GROUP=plugdev: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

The following command will create that file

`sudo echo "SYSFS{idVendor}==\"0403\", SYSFS{idProduct}==\"6001\", MODE=\"666\", GROUP=\"plugdev\"" > /etc/udev/rules.d/powertap.rules`

touch its mostly usefull to create an empty file. 
Remember that you can always open gedit as sudo, put that line and save the file.

Sam

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It still doesn't look like I made a file? sudo echo "SYSFS{idVendor}==\"0403\", SYSFS{idProduct}==\"6001\", MODE=\"666\", GROUP=\"plugdev\"" > /etc/udev/rules/powertap.rules 
bash: /etc/udev/rules/powertap.rules: No such file or directory

Comment: This command should work. Does the directory exist? can you `cd /etc/udev/rules`

Comment: cd /etc/udev/rules
bash: cd: /etc/udev/rules: No such file or directory

Comment: there is a file /etc/udev/rules.d.  Is this where I should place the file. Please forgive my lack of knowledge

Comment: Forgot about the problem of spaces. If any problems persist follow Sam's suggestion and use sudo gedit. Its less hassle.

Comment: I fixed the dire as you told, so the commands now works with directory "rules.d" instead of "rules"

Comment: Thanks for all of the help. Unfortunately the fix does not seem to change my permission problem with the USB device.